# Renumbering Page numbers with automatic TOC (Report Book) Jasperstudio 6.0.1

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Have a questions regarding page numbering in a report book. Point is: I have a client that does name-giving of page numbers like this:

- Chapter 1, page 6 (4th page that chapter)  =  1-4
- Chapter 2, page 12 (3th page that chapter) = 2-3
  etc.

Now, it's possible to make it happen with al different reports in the Content-section, but How do I display this pages/properties in the table of contents?

The report book supports some method that gives that bookmark-names back, but uses the $V{MASTER_CURRENT_PAGE} to print the page number. How could I show the page-numbers that are actually beneath the pages of the bookmark?

Please let me know, struggle with this one.

Regards, Gert